# Insert abnormal characters from a view to a table in db2 sql

Tags: sql, view, casting, db2, type-conversion

I am using DB2 i5/OS version. I have a `salesview` ready which looks like this:

```
    ORGNNAME                            SHIPTONO     ITEMNO

    Landoll Corporation                 00000001     EJ8-4001A       
    MCFA - Brittmoore Warehouse         ¿·11115R     114-04-4003
```

The column definitions are:

```
ORGNNAME CHAR(35) CCSID 65535   DEFAULT '' ,    
SHIPTO CHAR(8) CCSID 65535   DEFAULT '' 
ITEMNO CHAR(15) CCSID 65535   DEFAULT ''
```

**I want to unconditionally insert these values including the upside question mark in the table which I am not able to. Can some one help me out with this please**

I have another table with similar columns
lets say the 2 columns are `ORGNNAME` & `SHIPTONO`in the table. I want to `insert into table` from the `view`.
 The code I am using is similar to:

```
INSERT INTO ADCLIBT.TEMP11
(
SHIPTO,
SHIPMNTNO,
itnbr
)
 SELECT     
 cast(SHIPTONO as varchar(20)),
 SHIPNUMBER,
 ITEMNO
 FROM AMFLIB7.salesview WHERE SHIPDATE=1130204 AND ITEMNO LIKE ('1SD.055.%')
```

I tried doing it but gives me an error :

```
QL State: 22018
Vendor Code: -420
Message: [SQL0420] Character in CAST argument not valid
```

Comment: Can some one please try and answer this it is really importamt

Answer (score 0):

According to the 'Recovery' given by message SQL0420, you need to change the result data type of the `CAST` to one that can accept the value. A direct example could be:

```
CAST( SHIPTONO AS VARCHAR (20) CCSID 65535 )
```

Using CCSID 65535 for character data can be (or is) a very bad idea. It makes the data very un-portable and brings continuing problems as things change in the future, e.g., when definitions change or when data must be exchanged with other platforms (such as a PC). By definition, it is binary data that has no encoding and doesn't convert to other encodings such as EBCDIC<->ASCII. Default conversions are usually possible, but they must be applied for each individual connection between platforms. If not applied, unpredictable data results can (will) occur.